# How to set Mongo URL?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am trying to deploy my project, but when i check in the logs in my project logs I get the following error:

```
2016-11-07 20:23:45+08:00Error: MONGO_URL must be set in environment
5ar3
2016-11-07 20:23:45+08:00 at Object.<anonymous> (packages/mongo/remote_collection_driver.js:36:11)
5ar3
2016-11-07 20:23:45+08:00 at Object.defaultRemoteCollectionDriver (packages/underscore/underscore.js:750:1)
5ar3
2016-11-07 20:23:45+08:00 at new Mongo.Collection (packages/mongo/collection.js:103:40)
5ar3
2016-11-07 20:23:45+08:00 at AccountsServer.AccountsCommon (packages/accounts-base/accounts_common.js:23:18)
5ar3
2016-11-07 20:23:45+08:00 at new AccountsServer (packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js:18:5)
5ar3
2016-11-07 20:23:45+08:00 at meteorInstall.node_modules.meteor.accounts-base.server_main.js (packages/accounts-base/server_main.js:9:12)
5ar3
2016-11-07 20:23:45+08:00 at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime/.npm/package/node_modules/install/install.js:153:1)
5ar3
2016-11-07 20:23:45+08:00 at require (packages/modules-runtime/.npm/package/node_modules/install/install.js:82:1)
5ar3
2016-11-07 20:23:45+08:00 at /app/bundle/programs/server/packages/accounts-base.js:1838:15
5ar3
2016-11-07 20:23:45+08:00 at /app/bundle/programs/server/packages/accounts-base.js:1849:3
5ar3
2016-11-07 20:23:45+08:00Application exited with code: 1 signal: null
5ar3
2016-11-07 20:23:45+08:00Application process closed with code: 1 signal: null
5ar3
2016-11-07 20:24:08+08:00The container has crashed. A new container will be started to replace it.
k13z
2016-11-07 20:27:43+08:00Application process starting, version: 2 on apprunner (embedded)
k13z
2016-11-07 20:27:52+08:00/app/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/future.js:280
k13z
2016-11-07 20:27:52+08:00   throw(ex);
k13z
2016-11-07 20:27:52+08:00   ^
k13z
2016-11-07 20:27:52+08:00
k13z
2016-11-07 20:27:52+08:00Error: MONGO_URL must be set in environment
k13z
2016-11-07 20:27:52+08:00 at Object.<anonymous> (packages/mongo/remote_collection_driver.js:36:11)
k13z
2016-11-07 20:27:52+08:00 at Object.defaultRemoteCollectionDriver (packages/underscore/underscore.js:750:1)
k13z
2016-11-07 20:27:52+08:00 at new Mongo.Collection (packages/mongo/collection.js:103:40)
k13z
2016-11-07 20:27:52+08:00 at AccountsServer.AccountsCommon (packages/accounts-base/accounts_common.js:23:18)
k13z
2016-11-07 20:27:52+08:00 at new AccountsServer (packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js:18:5)
k13z
2016-11-07 20:27:52+08:00 at meteorInstall.node_modules.meteor.accounts-base.server_main.js (packages/accounts-base/server_main.js:9:12)
k13z
2016-11-07 20:27:52+08:00 at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime/.npm/package/node_modules/install/install.js:153:1)
k13z
2016-11-07 20:27:52+08:00 at require (packages/modules-runtime/.npm/package/node_modules/install/install.js:82:1)
k13z
2016-11-07 20:27:52+08:00 at /app/bundle/programs/server/packages/accounts-base.js:1838:15
k13z
2016-11-07 20:27:52+08:00 at /app/bundle/programs/server/packages/accounts-base.js:1849:3
```

From the error, it seems that it has something to do with how I set up my Mongo URL in my `settings.json` file

This is how I set it up in my `settings.json` file:

```
{
  "AWSAccessKeyId": "ID
  "AWSSecretAccessKey": "SECRETID",
  "public": {
    "analyticsSettings": {
      "Google Analytics" : {"trackingId": "sdsd-dlsfs-1"}
    },
    "galaxy.meteor.com": { 
     "env": { 
       "MONGO_URL": "mongodb://<dbuser>:<dbpassword>@dfd43435.mlab.com:2423/dbname" 
     } 
   }
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18359326/how-do-i-fix-error-mongo-url-must-be-set-in-environment-on-ubuntu-using-forev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it by deleting `settings.json` file and creating new one. I typed the content of the `settings.json` manually.

seems like there were hidden characters in the file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the `galaxy.meteor.com` outside of `public` field.

Comment: I am putting it outside :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you set your Mlab Information in the

```
mongodb://<dbuser>:<dbpassword>@dfd43435.mlab.com:2423/dbname
```

correctly?

dbuser/dbpassword/dbname have to be set in order to connect your database in with your deployed app.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using windows command prompt? first check by typing below command

`meteor mongo --url`

above command will display your **mongo url**.If you want to run any other database in your local app, go to root folder and type below command

`set MONGO_URL=mongodb://[username]:[password]@[host]:[port]/[databasename]`

eg-`set MONGO_URL=mongodb://root:abcde@ds049476.mlab.com:48474/mydb`

above command is working on windows